# jTable jquery validation engine error

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, jquery-jtable

I am using jTable jquery crud grid and its working fine. I am also using its validation engine files and working fine.

But main culprit is in validation engine file, .live() function which gives error. It says that function not exists. Then I removed .live and .die and replaced in validation engine file js with .on and .off functions.

After replacing, validation works fine too. But one bug I found is; When I update validation engine with new functions. On closing jquery dialog; it prompts with error red labels and closes that dialog. I am confused; why that red label prompts when I click close X sign of jquery dialog.

Even on live jtable site, .live function gives error if you close dialog or open dialog on add record link thats why error is not producing.

If any workaround or update on this I want to get rid off from that red label prompt on closing dialog.

Comment: Could you show your code, or put it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Minus rating????????? Very shame that it is much valid question/issue from my side and someone allow it to close or do minus rating.

Comment: For code snipplet, it is url http://jtable.org/Demo/UsingWithValidationEngine2 and clicking on add new record and  closing it throws error. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working after updating validationEngine file compatible with .on and .off function. and Also got rid off from on lost focus error (show error only on submit).

Replaced code:

```
formCreated: function (event, data) {
                    data.form.validationEngine();
                }
TO
formCreated: function (event, data) {
                    data.form.validationEngine('attach', {
                        binded: true
                    });
                }
```